# Optimizing Observable.fromEvent on the window

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my file manager UI, each file item is observing the window `wheel` event. Whenever the file item enters the viewport, the file item component will then start to load it's image. This is useful when having a large set of files on a single page. But I ran into an issue where my app would lag at about 20+ files showing in the page.

```
...
// observe to user scrolling through the page
// I store the subscription to unsubscribe when the image has loaded
// or when the file item component gets destroyed
this.sub = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'wheel').subscribe(() => {

    const container = this.elementRef.nativeElement

    if (container.getBoundingClientRect().top < window.innerHeight) {

        // Start loading the image when it enters the viewport
        this.startDownload$.next(true)
    }
})
```

Is there a way to optimize this subscription?

Update (30/05/2019):
This is a very inefficient method to achieve what I intended. It is better to have a "central" service that listens to the scroll event, your components can then subscribe/unsubscribe to/from that service. Do not setup the same event listener on multiple components.

Comment: So you setup the event listener for every file?

Comment: note: 'wheel' event is non-standard, use rather 'scroll'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need limit number of requests due to too many events try to use debounceTime operator.

> https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounce

```
Observable.fromEvent(window, 'wheel')
    .debounceTime(300)
    .subscribe(() => {
        console.log(window)
    })
```